# Expanding data frame which contain list in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame which contains list inside it.

```
df <- data.frame(
      id=c(1:4),
      a=I(list(c(1,"a1"),2,c("a31","a32","a33"),"a4")),
      b=I(list(2,c("b1","b2",3),c("b3","b4"),4))
    ); print(df)

  id            a         b
1  1        1, a1         2
2  2            2 b1, b2, 3
3  3 a31, a32....    b3, b4
4  4           a4         4
```

Now, I need to `unnest` the list to obtain data frame like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
      id=c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4),
      a=c(1,"a1",2,2,2,"a31","a31","a32","a32","a33","a33","a4"),
      b=c(2,2,"b1","b2",3,"b3","b3","b3","b4","b4","b4",4)
    ) ; print(df2)

   id   a  b
1   1   1  2
2   1  a1  2
3   2   2 b1
4   2   2 b2
5   2   2  3
6   3 a31 b3
7   3 a31 b3
8   3 a32 b3
9   3 a32 b4
10  3 a33 b4
11  3 a33 b4
12  4  a4  4
```

I used to use `unnest()` for those which contains the same number of list elements in some rows/columns, but current data frame contains different number of elements in some rows and columns. Currently I am facing the following error.

```
> target <- c("id","a","b")
> df %>% unnest(cols=target)
Error in `unnest()`:
! In row 3, can't recycle input of size 3 to size 2.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Due to unpredictability of *where it happens* (rowwise/columnwise) and *how many elements it will contain*, I cannot find appropriate approach to tackle with this. The number of columns and its names cannot be determined in advance.

I appreciate your suggestion especially simple ones which can be integrated into current pipe operation in `dplyr`. `Base R` and other approaches are also welcomed.

====

*Rreproducible example data*

Let me share a reproductible example of the actual data frame that I am working on. It did not work with solutions from @ThomasIsCoding. I suspect it caused by NULL but it was not the reason. Blank/Null is not necessarily replicated.

```
structure(list(cluster = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), st_sub_main_th = list(
    "hira", NULL, "tsuma", "tsuma", NULL, c("other", "hira")), 
    roo_main = list("2", "4", "3", "2", c("1", "3"), c("6", "7", 
    "2", "1")), st_con_rt = list("sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room", 
        "sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room"), st_con_tr = list(
        "terrace", c("terrace", "direct"), "terrace", "terrace", 
        "terrace", "direct"), st_adsb = list("add", "add", "add", 
        "sub", "add", "sub"), st_th = list(NULL, "tsuma", NULL, 
        NULL, "hira", NULL), st_sub2_main_th = list(NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, "hira", "hira", "tsuma"), isstilt = list(NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: You have more problems than the size of the elements in the lists: those lists mix `numeric` and `character` elements, they won't easily be "converted" into a simple vector/column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
exec(pmap_df, df, expand_grid)

# A tibble: 15 × 9
   cluster st_sub_main_th roo_main st_con_rt st_con_tr st_adsb st_th st_sub2_main_th isstilt
   <chr>   <chr>          <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <chr> <chr>           <chr>  
 1 1       hira           2        sub-room  terrace   add     NA    NA              NA     
 2 2       NA             4        main-room terrace   add     tsuma NA              NA     
 3 2       NA             4        main-room direct    add     tsuma NA              NA     
 4 3       tsuma          3        sub-room  terrace   add     NA    NA              NA     
 5 4       tsuma          2        sub-room  terrace   sub     NA    hira            NA     
 6 5       NA             1        main-room terrace   add     hira  hira            NA     
 7 5       NA             3        main-room terrace   add     hira  hira            NA     
 8 6       other          6        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
 9 6       other          7        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
10 6       other          2        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
11 6       other          1        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
12 6       hira           6        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
13 6       hira           7        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
14 6       hira           2        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0      
15 6       hira           1        sub-room  direct    sub     NA    tsuma           0
```

Note that the above is equivalent to:

```
bind_rows(exec(pmap, df, expand_grid))
```

In case you have mixed datatypes, consider the following:

```
exec(rbind, !!!exec(pmap, df, expand_grid))
```

Comment: It is quite handy to execute within pipe operation. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## (Update) If your nested dataframe has `NULL`s

Since you may have `NULL`s, you can play the following trick for the new data in your question

```
d <- list2DF(lapply(df, \(u) replace(u, lengths(u) == 0, "")))
do.call(
    rbind,
    do.call(Map, c(expand.grid, d, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
)
```

which gives

```
    cluster st_sub_main_th roo_main st_con_rt st_con_tr st_adsb st_th
1         1           hira        2  sub-room   terrace     add
2.1       2                       4 main-room   terrace     add tsuma
2.2       2                       4 main-room    direct     add tsuma
3         3          tsuma        3  sub-room   terrace     add      
4         4          tsuma        2  sub-room   terrace     sub
5.1       5                       1 main-room   terrace     add  hira
5.2       5                       3 main-room   terrace     add  hira
6.1       6          other        6  sub-room    direct     sub
6.2       6           hira        6  sub-room    direct     sub
6.3       6          other        7  sub-room    direct     sub
6.4       6           hira        7  sub-room    direct     sub
6.5       6          other        2  sub-room    direct     sub
6.6       6           hira        2  sub-room    direct     sub
6.7       6          other        1  sub-room    direct     sub
6.8       6           hira        1  sub-room    direct     sub
    st_sub2_main_th isstilt
1
2.1
2.2
3
4              hira
5.1            hira
5.2            hira
6.1           tsuma       0
6.2           tsuma       0
6.3           tsuma       0
6.4           tsuma       0
6.5           tsuma       0
6.6           tsuma       0
6.7           tsuma       0
6.8           tsuma       0
```

---

## If your nested dataframe has NO `NULL`s

You can try `expand.grid` with `Map` like below

```
do.call(
    rbind,
    do.call(Map, c(expand.grid, df, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
)
```

which gives

```
   id   a  b
1   1   1  2
2   1  a1  2
3   2   2 b1
4   2   2 b2
5   2   2  3
6   3 a31 b3
7   3 a32 b3
8   3 a33 b3
9   3 a31 b4
10  3 a32 b4
11  3 a33 b4
12  4  a4  4
```

Comment: Thank you. In actual data frame, columns cannot be dynamycally specified. I replaced `Map(expand.grid, id, a, b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` by  `Map(expand.grid, !!sym(target), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` but faced an error `Can't convert a character vector to a symbol`. 
I also simply place `target` without `!!sym()` but it returned `'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [1]`.  Anything wrong?

Comment: @HSJ You can try my updated solution

Comment: It worked well for test data in the post, but I got a empty data when I tried it with my actual data frame. I suspected it was caused by NULL values but it was not the issue. I appreciate if it happens with you as well..

Comment: @HSJ yes, `NULL` produces the issue, but you can try replace it by `""` or `NA` before you proceed with `expand.grid`. See my update

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by `unnest`ing each column at a time.  However, you need to cast things into `character` first, otherwise the unnesting won't work, since you'd be trying to create a vector/column with both `numeric` and `character` elements.

```
library(purrr) # For map()
library(tidyr) # For unnest()
library(dplyr) # For mutate()

df %>%
mutate(a = map(a, as.character),
       b = map(b, as.character)) %>%
unnest(cols = a) %>%
unnest(cols = b)
```

##### Update with sample data:

On your sample data, you'll also need to replace the `NULL`s with something else, otherwise, they'll disappear with the intermediate unnesting:

```
df2 <- structure(list(
  cluster = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
  st_sub_main_th = list("hira", NULL, "tsuma", "tsuma", NULL, c("other", "hira")),
  roo_main = list("2", "4", "3", "2", c("1", "3"), c("6", "7", "2", "1")),
  st_con_rt = list("sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room", "sub-room", "main-room", "sub-room"),
  st_con_tr = list("terrace", c("terrace", "direct"), "terrace", "terrace", "terrace", "direct"),
  st_adsb = list("add", "add", "add", "sub", "add", "sub"),
  st_th = list(NULL, "tsuma", NULL, NULL, "hira", NULL),
  st_sub2_main_th = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, "hira", "hira", "tsuma"),
  isstilt = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "0")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 %>%
mutate_if(is.list, map, coalesce, NA_character_) %>%
mutate_if(is.list, map, as.character) %>%
unnest(st_sub_main_th) %>%
unnest(roo_main) %>%
unnest(st_con_rt) %>%
unnest(st_con_tr) %>%
unnest(st_adsb) %>%
unnest(st_th) %>%
unnest(st_sub2_main_th) %>%
unnest(isstilt)
```

Comment: Thank you, one issue is that I cannot fix the number and name of columns beforehand...

Comment: Maybe use `... %>% Reduce(unnest, which(sapply(., is.list)), init = .)` so you don't need to specify each unnest individually.